# Run cURL command every 5 seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

This is the command that I want to run -

```
curl --request POST --data-binary @payload.txt --header "carriots.apiKey:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --verbose http://api.carriots.com/streams
```

This basically sends a data stream to a server.

I want to run this command every 5 seconds. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can run in while loop.

```
while sleep 5; do cmd; done
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use `while..loop`. you can use [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command.

```
watch -n 5 cmd
```

Comment: Ive heard that using a loop is not a very efficient way to achieve this. Im sorry I'm absolutely new to linux.

Comment: @ArchitArora Loop is not efficient where you heard? every thing is useful but depend on situation and time. Any way find my updated answer.

Comment: Additionally should use flag `-s` to silent-out verbosity if used along with `--raw` to see response. `watch -n 5 "curl --raw some.url -s"`

Comment: Won't work with curl if the reply is too long it will be cut out as watch has a maximum number of characters output.

Answer (score 13):

Another simple way to accomplish the same task is:

`watch -n {{seconds}} {{your-command}}`

For example, every 900 milliseconds (note the double quotes around "your-command"):

```
watch -n 0.9 "curl 'https://public-cloud.abstratium.dev/user/site'"
```